# Prove the stronger version of the Kolmogorov inequality

Tags: probability, probability-theory

> Let $\xi_1, \ldots, \xi_n   $ be a sequence of *n* independent random variables, each $\xi_i $ having a symmetric distribution. That is $P(\xi_i \in A) = P(\xi_i \in -A) $ for any Borel set $ A \subseteq \mathcal{R}$. Assume that $E \xi_i^{2m} < \infty$,$i=1,2,...,n.$ Prove the stronger version of the Kolmogorov inequality:
> $$P\left(\max_{1\le k \le n } |\xi_1+\ldots +\xi_k| \ge t \right) \le \frac{E(\xi_1+\ldots +\xi_n)^{2m}}{t^{2m}}.$$

I know how to prove the usual Kolmogorov inequality. The first step is: we consider the events $C_k = \{ \omega: |\xi_1 +...+ \xi_i|- (m_1+...+m_i)| <t  $ for $1 \leq i <k, |\xi_1 +...+ \xi_k|- (m_1+...+m_k)| \geq t$}, $C = \cup_{k=1}^n C_k$. It is clear that C is the event whose probability is estimated in the Kolmogorov inequality, and that $C_k$ are pair-wise disjoint.

I don't know how to change the proof of the usual Kolmogorov inequality to show the stronger version.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [A stronger version of Kolmogorov Inequality](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1048854/a-stronger-version-of-kolmogorov-inequality)

Comment: @GabrielRomon But I didn't understand that solution.

Comment: Since $E(\xi_i) = 0$, the sequence of sums $S_n = \xi_1 + \dots + \xi_n$ is a martingale. By Doob's martingale inequality, we have $P(\max_{1 \leq k \leq n}|S_k| \geq t) \leq t^{-p}E(|S_n|^p)$ for all $p \geq 1$. Take $p = 2m$. See page 235 of https://services.math.duke.edu/~rtd/PTE/PTE5_011119.pdf The main point is that $(|S_n|^p)$ is a nonnegative submartingale, and for nonnegative submartingales $X$, we have $P(\max_{1\leq k \leq n}X_k \geq t) \leq t^{-1}E(X_n)$

Comment: @Mason sorry, I don't learn martingale yet.